# Why will the following line crash my Android app?

Tags: java, android

The following line, no mather where placed where will crash my Android program.

```
EditText editText1;
double pro = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
```

Additional code:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btsub"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not experieced with debugging.

EDIT--

The following will show a toast containing: "Something is real wrong"

```
try {
                    if(editText1 != null) {
                        pro = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
                    } else {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Something real wrong";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Empty";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
```

Comment: Post the logcat, please

Comment: You tried to set some text first ?

Comment: Can you post the error lines at your logcat.Also you might be initializing editText1 wrong.

Comment: Please paste the logs/error?

Comment: I am not good with debugging so i dont know how to post the logcat...

Comment: Check this [Like][1], it's may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474319/how-to-parse-a-double-from-edittext-to-textview-android

Comment: jipje44, this is how you can save your logcat: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file or from eclipse logcat view, just select the interested lines and click on the disk icon

Comment: Thanks! It is all clear now and my questions is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should check if your `editText1` is `null` (this was your actual problem! *) than check if a `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

*) Your problem was that you just defined a uninitialized *reference* to your control. You need to get a reference with the `findViewById()` function:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
double pro;
try {
    if(editText1 != null) {
        pro = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        // you have an coding problem ;-)
        // this should now just happen if you change the id in your xml
    }
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // input was no number or an empty string
}
```

Comment: I get into the // you have an coding problem ;-) section. With the updated code.

Comment: @jipje44 You have to initialize your `EditText` variable

Comment: You have to address your control with [`findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). I'll update my code.

Comment: @jipje44 update is online ;-)

Comment: It is working now :) I was missing EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.detailsline); ps why did i got downvotes? I mean can't i ask a beginner question?