# How to get double from EditText the right way?

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-edittext, double

Does anyone know how to parse a double from an EditText?

I know how to do it, but it isn't the right way I think. Does anyone have best practises?

Thank you.

Comment: Whar have you tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a double from EditText to TextView? (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474319/how-to-parse-a-double-from-edittext-to-textview-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try this:

```
double value;
String text =your_edittext.getText().toString();
if(!text.isEmpty())
try
{
   value= Double.parseDouble(text);
   // it means it is double
} catch (Exception e1) {
   // this means it is not double 
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How about checking if the Edittext is a double and checking if the edittext isn't empty?

Comment: Looks good, is the try and catch for the parsing of the double?

Comment: **Double.parseDouble(text);** is for the parsing but if it gives error it means it is not double

Comment: Alright I see what you did there, so you can throw a toast in the exception saying it's not a double. And you can set the double value == 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you type in EditText is String.

**How to check if edittext is empty?**

```
String str = edit_text.getText().toString();
if (str.trim().equals("")
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "EditText is empty.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Parse a double from an EditText (Kotlin)**

- [toDouble()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double.html) function works great but if  the string is not a valid representation of a number. Throw ***NumberFormatException*** Exception.
- [*toDoubleOrNull()*](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) function returns a double value. if the string is not a valid representation of a number return ***null***

**Implementation**

```
fun parseToDouble(value :Editable): Double { 
    if(value.isNotEmpty()){
        val result = value.trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if(result != null) 
            return result
        else 
            return 0.0
    }else { 
      return 0.0
   }
}
```

**Or above code can be simplified using [Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions)**

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble(): Double { 
    if(this.isNotEmpty()){
        val result = this.trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if(result != null) 
            return result
        else 
            return 0.0
    }else { 
      return 0.0
   }
}
```

- The "*this*" keyword inside an extension function corresponds to the receiver object.  it can also be remove

**Or above code can be simplified using Kotlin [When expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression)**

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble(): Double { 
    return when(isNotEmpty()){
    true -> {
        val result = trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if(result != null) result else 0.0
      }
   else -> 0.0
}
```

**Or above code can be simplified by Convert to expression body ([“return” vs expression body](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/return-vs-expression-body/12485))**

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble(): Double = when(isNotEmpty()){
    true -> {
        val result = trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if(result != null) result else 0.0
      }
   else -> 0.0
}
```

**Or above code can be simplified using Kotlin [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)**

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble() = when(isNotEmpty()){
    true -> trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()?: 0.0
    else -> 0.0
}
```

**Simplest version (best)**

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble() = trim().toString().toDoubleOrNull()?: 0.0
```

Or

```
fun Editable.parseToDouble() = toString().toDoubleOrNull()?: 0.0
```

**Notes**: similarly you can create **parseToInt** and **parseToLong** function